# Linear Recurrences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I was working on linear recurrence... But I am having trouble with it.

$a_0 = 1;
a_1 = 2;
a_k = 4a_{k-1} - 2a_{k-2}$

I found $a_2$ which is $$4a_1 - 2 a_0=4\cdot2 - 2\cdot 1 = 6$$
I found $a_3$ which is $$4a_2 - 2 a_1= 4 \cdot6 - 2 \cdot 2= 20$$
I found $a_4$ which is $$4a_3 - 2 a_2=4 \cdot 20 - 2 \cdot 6 = 68$$

Now I am looking for general formula of n'ts term... And I am having difficulties wih it.
I brought it to quadratic:
$$a_k = 4a_{k-1} - 2a_{k-2}$$

$$a_k-4a_{k-1}+ 2a+{k-2} = 0$$
$$r^k-4a^{k-1} + 2a^{k-2}=0$$
I did substitution

$$r^k-2 (r^2-4r +2)$$

Now I am solving quadratic $r^2 - 4r +2=0$

$$D = b^2 - 4ac$$

$$D = 16 - 8$$

$$r = \frac{4\pm\sqrt{8}}4$$

And now I have problems.
Even if I solve $r_1$ and $r_2$

it will give me $r_1=3.41$ and $r_2 = 0.59 $

(all troncated)

Now if i have discriminant positive I a substituting it into the formula

$$a(k) = Ar_1^k + Br_2^k$$

It gives me $1 = A\cdot3.41^0 + 0.59\cdot{B^0}$

$$A + B = 1$$

And

$$3.41\cdot{A^1} + B\cdot0.59^1 = 2$$

And I have a system:

$$A+2 = 1$$

$$3.41A + 0.59B = 2$$

I substitute and solve it...

$$A = 1-B$$

$$3.41(1-B) + 0.59B = 2$$

$$3.41 - 3.41B + 0.59B = 2$$
$$3.41 - 4B = 2$$

$$4B = 1(1.41)$$

$$B = 0.35$$

$$A + 0.35 =1$$

$$A = 0.65$$

Final Formula

$$0.65 (3.41)^k + 0.35(0.59)^k$$

I believe I did it incorectrly.  Because when I am trying to use my formula it does not return correct results for my sequence.

It works with a(1) where k is 0. But it does not work with a(2) and a(3) etc...

I troncated the results so it is easier to type what I did. I did my best to show what I did.

Please, help me with it. Help me understand how to do it and where I did wrong.
Please, help me guys.

Comment: are you familiar with generating functions?

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting to be proper latex but I got as far as "r1,2 = (4=/1 sqrt(8))/4".  For this I really didn't know what you meant, does this line possibly have a typo?

Comment: Steps in the substitution are inaccurate and the roots of the quadratic equation are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For a cleaner resolution:

Trying an exponential behavior $a_k=r^k$ gives

$$r^k=4r^{k-1}-2r^{k-2},$$i.e. for a nontrivial solution ($r\ne0$)$$r^2-4r+2=0.$$

By the well-known quadratic formula

$$r=2\pm\sqrt2,$$

so that a general solution is of the form

$$a_k=a(2+\sqrt2)^k+b(2-\sqrt2)^k.$$

Plugging the initial conditions allows to solve for the constans $a,b$:

$$a_0=1=a(2+\sqrt2)^0+b(2-\sqrt2)^0=a+b.$$
$$a_1=2=a(2+\sqrt2)^1+b(2-\sqrt2)^1=2+\sqrt2(a-b)\implies a=b.$$

Then

$$\color{green}{a_k=\frac12(2+\sqrt2)^k+\frac12(2-\sqrt2)^k}.$$

As one checks,

$$a_0=\frac12+\frac12=1.$$
$$a_1=\frac12(2+\sqrt2)+\frac12(2-\sqrt2)=2.$$
$$a_2=\frac12(2+\sqrt2)^2+\frac12(2-\sqrt2)^2=2^2+\sqrt2^2=6=4\cdot2-2\cdot1.$$
$$a_3=\frac12(2+\sqrt2)^3+\frac12(2-\sqrt2)^3=2^3+3\cdot2\cdot\sqrt2^2=20=4\cdot6-2\cdot2.$$
$$\cdots$$

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but how did you come up with r = 2 + or - sqrt(2) ???

As the quadratic formula is D = b^2 - 4ac, what will give us

4^2 - 4*1*2 = 16-8
D = 8

Sorry for messy dispay . I have not learnt how to use formulas yet.

If it is not hard for you could you please explain to me where did you get sqrt(2) because as far as I can see discriminant is 8.
Because I do want to understand this.

If it is not hard for  you, please explain.

And yes, I definetelly will learn how no use formulas!

Comment: Shulyak: There is a good slide show that explains what Yves did: (http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2008-09/S/1019/Website_files/21-linear-recurrences.pdf)